GNU make unable to find existing folder
I am working in Visual Studio Code with GNU Make 4.4.1. I have a set of source code I have been trying to compile, but I'm encountering an error that doesn't make any sense to me.
I run Terminal->Run Build Task... which accesses the tasks.json file and tries to run
make -C "C:\My Path\Details Not Important\sourcecontrol\XYZ_program" -d
The power shell comes up and I get the following messages reported back to me:
make: Entering directory '/c/My Path/Details Not Important/sourcecontrol'
make: *** C:\My Path\Details Not Important\sourcecontrol\XYZ_program: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/c/My Path/Details Not Important/sourcecontrol'

The relevant parts of the tasks.json are:
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make",
        "args": [
            "-C \"C:/My Path/Details Not Important/sourcecontrol/XYZ_program\"",
            "-d",
            "-f Makefile"
        ],

Does anyone have an explanation of what I'm doing wrong that gnu make can't find the directory?
I can navigate to the path just fine in the Terminal, in cmd, and in Explorer.
I've used both the backslash "-C \"C:\\My Path\\Details Not Important\\sourcecontrol\\XYZ_program\"" and forward slash "-C \"C:/My Path/Details Not Important/sourcecontrol/XYZ_program\"" characters in the path name.
I've even gone through the effort of using the equivalent short path for the directory and I still get a similar message.
I've tried dropping the directory change and instead identifying the Makefile in that directory directly, with the full path name. Gnu make still cannot find it, but I get a lot of useless information as it tries to work around a missing makefile.
Edit:
The Makefile tools extension has not been terribly helpful. I have set the tool's Makefile in the Makefile Project Outline to the desired Makefile. Nonetheless, when VSCode attempts to configure dry-run output, it times out. I do not see anything terribly useful in the output from that - just a bunch of boilerplate warnings.
Edit2: Yes, I did try separating the "-C path" into "-C", and "path" and "-f makefile" into "-f", and "makefile". It made no difference; neither format worked.

Would it help to use the 'Makefile tools' extension? It just might clear up the path problem for you, or help you understand what's wrong.

Should "-C" and "C:\My Path\Details Not Important\sourcecontrol\XYZ_program" and "-f" and "Makefile" be separate in args? I don't know how Make interprets a switch and its argument when they are quoted, but it seems wrong.
